# How to stop field validation on first error?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I have a form in Symfony 2.8 with a field like this:

```
$builder->add('a', TextType::class, [
            'label' => '',
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(
                    [
                        'message' => 'foo'
                    ]
                ),
                new Regex(
                    [
                        'pattern' => '/^\d+$/',
                        'message' => 'bar'
                    ]
                ),
                new GreaterThan(
                    [
                        'value' => 0,
                        'message' => 'empty'
                    ]
                )
            ]
]);
```

`

When the field value is empty, we have an error message from each constraint. How to prevent executing the constraints defined after the first constraint which has failed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is a more straight-forward solution to your problem, but you could use a [callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) to validate the field, and have it add the error message at the first failed check.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use differents **Error Levels**:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/severity.html

```
 new NotBlank(
                [
                    'message' => 'foo',
                    'payload' => 
                        [
                            'severity' => 'lv1'                  
                        ]
                ]
            ),
...
```

If you set different levels (ex. 'lv1', 'lv2') you can simply create a show logic over your errors choosing what to show.

An alternative way is to check every single property of your entity, looking for errors:

```
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validateProperty($entity, 'name of the property');
if (count($errors)) {
    // Show only the first error
}
```

There are also other ways to achieve this, but you should give us more details about your code logic.